# How to use result of jdbc interpreter and cassandra interpreter in a single paragraph in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to make a notebook in apache zeppelin by combining results of two different interpreters. One is jdbc and another is cassandra. How can i combine the result of both interpreter in a single paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible right now. There is some work done to create a shared `ResourcePool` so that different interpreters can share variables between them but as far as I know, only the Spark interpreter can use it.

I will update the Cassandra interpreter so that it will read data from share `ResourcePool` if it exists but this improvement won't be available until the next release of Zeppelin